# How to configurre Typesafe Console for Play Framework 2.1.3 Applcation?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.1

I tried to find any documentation on how to configure Typesafe Console for Play Framework 2.1.3 Applcation but have no success. Please provide steps to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Play instrumentation in Typesafe Console is first available in 1.3.0, which has only been released as an RC (RELEASE CANDIDATE).

http://resources.typesafe.com/console/docs/1.3.0-RC1/manual/overview.html